# Can I treat items found through a Promise.all as a firebase collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am stuck in what I thought was a very simple use case: I have a list of client ids in an array. All I want to do is fetch all those clients and "watch" them (using the `.onSnapshot`).

To fetch the client objects, it is nice and simple, I simply go through the array and get each client by their id. The code looks something like this:

```
  const accessibleClients = ['client1', 'client2', 'client3']

  const clients = await Promise.all(
    accessibleClients.map(async clientId => {
      return db
        .collection('clients')
        .doc(clientId)
        .get()
    })
  )
```

If I just needed the list of clients, it would be fine, but I need to perform the `.onSnapshot` on it to see changes of the clients I am displaying. Is this possible to do? How can I get around this issue?

Comment: No, promises don't react to changes, they only resolve once. You'd need some kind of Observable.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with AngularFire so it is a bit different. But i also had the problem that i need to listen to unrelated documents which can not be queried.

I solved this with an object which contains all the snapshot listeners. This allows you to unsubscribe from individual client snapshots or from all snapshot if you do not need it anymore.

```
const accessibleClients = ['client1', 'client2', 'client3'];
const clientSnapshotObject = {};
const clientDataArray = [];

accessibleClients.forEach(clientId => {
    clientSnapshotArray[clientId] = {
        db.collection('clients').doc(clientId).onSnapshot(doc => {
            const client = clientDataArray.find(client => doc.id === client.clientId);

            if (client) {
                const index = clientDataArray.findIndex(client => doc.id === client.clientId);
                clientDataArray.splice(index, 1 , doc.data())
            } else {
                clientDataArray.push(doc.data());
            }
        })
    };
})
```

With the clientIds of the `accessibleClients` array, i create an object of DocumentSnapshots with the clientId as property key.

The snapshot callback function pushes the specific client data into the `clientDataArray`. If a snapshot changes the callback function replaces the old data with the new data.

I do not know your exact data model but i hope this code helps with your problem.